# How can I get the bottle glossy W/O the label too?

Tags: modeling, node-editor

Having a little trouble with getting the bottle glossy and not the label. As you can see there's a glass node... so the bottle *should* have some gloss anyways --right? When I use the diffuse node (instead of the glossy node) the label has the nice matte finish (as it's supposed too) but the bottle has no glossyness. But when adding a glossy node instead of the diffuse that makes the label glossy and yet still does nothing to add gloss. What am I doing wrong? Suggestions?[image]

[image]

Comment: no .blend this time?

Comment: Attached just now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your setup other than the lights and the surroundings of the bottle... Remember, glossy materials reflect the environment. So make the environment something worth reflecting...

[image]

Instead of adding a bunch of point lights, create large light sources...

Since you are so invested in creating bottles, take some time and study how most images of glass and alcohol and beverages are lit. You'll find out soon enough that when dealing with glass most photographers have big light sources and interesting patterns to be reflected on the shiny surfaces.

One more thing to try in your setup is to use the yellow letters as a mask for  the glossy shader, so that the purple part of the label can be diffuse and only the writing has a reflective surface

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks. You lit the scene well. I'm not sure how to use "yellow letters as a mask for the glossy shader" --I'm assuming a 'mask' is something like an alpha channel in Photoshop. Something more to learn now :)

Comment: For the yellow letters use the node setup on the second image

Comment: OIC! I just copied it node by node and I can see that letters are reflective now. So what it looks like (to me anyways) is that using the Hue/Sat Value along with the Curves you selected a value which was the letters and by doing so it creates kind of a faux alpha channel or what you call a mask?

Comment: The goal is to have a black and white image. The letters should be white and the rest black. The hue/sat/value controls what colors will be turned into black and white, the curve is to make the darker areas be closer to black by increasing contrast. The resulting image is fed into the **fac** socket that controls the mix with the glossy shader. Any image can be used as fac. It doesn't have to be ***alpha*** channel

Comment: Thank you. Last question - What does fac stand for :)...?

Comment: >Fac input:
Blend weight to use for mixing two shaders; at zero it uses the first shader entirely and at one the second shader.