# How to make gold hot stamping on the box?

Tags: modeling, uv

Dear All Sifoos here,

I am new to Blender. I have a question, how can i make a gold hot stamping effect on my render of the following sample box image?

Thanks in advance.

Note: This 3D made in Photoshop.

[image: Sample photo as reference]

Comment: Specify your **render engine**, and add images of what you have tried so far. Use the edit button to improve your post.

Comment: Just use a texture to mask between two different shaders, one gold one purple

Comment: see this related post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44806/how-can-i-get-the-bottle-glossy-w-o-the-label-too/44812#44812

Comment: Dear @cegaton, thanks for your related post, it helps me alot to understand how  node works.