# black around an image set as image texture (jpg or png)

Tags: texturing, uv

I have made a cylinder, unwrapped.
I want to wrap an image on it, but not to cover all the cylinder.
If a scale it down, i see black around my label instead of object's material.

How can i fix this?
I'm novice in blender
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8706/what-is-the-right-way-to-apply-an-image-texture-over-a-glass-or-plastic-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44806/how-can-i-get-the-bottle-glossy-w-o-the-label-too/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447

Comment: i read carefully. none of them is my case. maybe i did not explain well, so here is the link for the blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bjgZb1YI1XMO-NBQGsATB0veI4jiqknU/view?usp=sharing